# Representing Composite Types under ''

Tags: postgresql, types, composite

I'm currently using Neon to use Postgres from a serverless origin and have been needing to find a way to use ARRAY and ROW under ''s with no success.

Example

```
UPDATE communication.messages
SET message_content = row ('test', ARRAY [
    row (
        'test','test','0',
        ARRAY [
            row ('test','2','true')
        ] :: message_embed_field[])
    ]::message_embed[],
    ARRAY []::message_attachment[],ARRAY []::message_button[], 'true')
WHERE id = 'dd998de9-2da9-4fda-9530-fbe90c078f18'
RETURNING *;
```

Have tried the following

```
UPDATE communication.messages
SET message_content = '(''test'',''{"(''test'',''test'',''0'',''{"(''test'',''2'',''true'')"}'')"}'',''{}'',''{}'',''true'')'
WHERE id = 'dd998de9-2da9-4fda-9530-fbe90c078f18'
RETURNING *;
```

but have not been able to solve the following

```
[2024-03-03 22:40:07] [22P02] ERROR: malformed array literal: "'{}'"
[2024-03-03 22:40:07] Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
[2024-03-03 22:40:07] Position: 54
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is not an answer, but storing arrays of a composite type in a database is a bad idea that you will regret as soon as you try to use the data inside the database. If you don't use the data inside the database, store it as a single `text` or `json`.

Comment: Do those arrays inhibit search capability?

Comment: Depends on what you want to search, but probably yes.